# Java HashMap is becoming null after exiting from if condition

Tags: java, hashmap

In first if condition putting a value in HashMap & in next if condition the HashMap is null.

```
    HashMap<String, List> operation = new HashMap<>();
    List method = Arrays.asList("get","put","post");
    ArrayList <String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().contains("/") && !entry.getKey().contains("$ref")){
            currentKey = entry.getKey();
            operation.put(entry.getKey(),params); // Here value is assigned successfully
        }
        if(method.contains(entry.getKey())){
             operation.get(currentKey).add(entry.getKey()); //Here its null point exception & HashMap has no data
        }
       
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            iterate((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is where the problems are:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().contains("/") 
        && !entry.getKey().contains("$ref")) {
        currentKey = entry.getKey();
        operation.put(entry.getKey(), params); // Here value is assigned
                                               // successfully
    }
    if (method.contains(entry.getKey())) {
         operation.get(currentKey).add(entry.getKey()); 
                                               // Here its null pointer
                                               // exception & HashMap has no data
    }
    ...
 }
```

The first test is testing the value of the key.  The second test is testing whether the key is contained in `methods`.  These tests are different.

Based on the code that you have shown us, there are actually 4 possibilities for the outcomes of these tests:

- both tests succeed
- both tests fail
- first test succeeds, and second test fails
- first test fails, and second test succeeds

The last possibility is the probably the cause of the NPE.

If (for example) the key does not contain the string `"/"`, but it the `method` string (or collection or whatever) *does* contain the key, then:

1. The `operation.put...` statement IS NOT executed
2. The `operation.get...` statement IS executed ... and will NPE because the `operation.get` call returns `null`.

And there is this is exacerbated by a second problem.   When the first test fails, it won't perform the `currentKey = entry.getKey();` statement.  That means that `operation.get(currentKey)` will be using a `currentKey` value *from a previous step*.  The value could even be `null`.  (Note that `operation.get(null)` will most likely return `null`.)

---

In short, your code appears to contain at least two bugs, and the most plausible explanation for the missing `operation` map entry is that your code didn't put it there!  (It is not *becoming* `null`.)

(We do not need to hypothesize a flaw in `HashMap` to explain this.)

If this doesn't explain the problem to your satisfaction, you will need to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question ... so that we can run it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't being consistent with `currentKey` **and** your second `if` is wrong. You are testing `method` but then invoking on `operation`. Let's fix that. Like,

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> operation = new HashMap<>();
List<String> method = Arrays.asList("get", "put", "post");
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String currentKey = entry.getKey();
    if (currentKey.contains("/") && !currentKey.contains("$ref")) {
        operation.put(currentKey, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    if (operation.containsKey(currentKey)) {
        operation.get(currentKey).add(currentKey);
    }

    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        iterate((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, in the second if - my test is based on method(List) if matches add to existing key of operation HashMap.  Note : when I declare the HashMap in class variable its working fine but locally facing this issue. My question why in second if condition HashMap is null when in first condition its assigned a value (guess I'm missing something conceptual).Thanks in advance